# scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String; (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I want to read the file , My file format is :
  **12334  this:23,word:21,teacher:23**

```
   val fp = "/user/user_id.txt"
   sc.textFile(fp).map { s =>
   val Array(did, info_s) = s.split("\t")
   val info = info_s.split(",").map { kv =>
      val Array(k, v) = kv.split(":")
      (k, v.toDouble)
    }.toSeq
    (did, info)
  }
```

this scala  error appeared.How this happended?

```
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@51443799 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
at com.test.news.IO$$anonfun$1.apply(App.scala:58)
at com.test.news.IO$$anonfun$1.apply(App.scala:57)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The line 58 is  **val Array(did, info_s) = s.split("\t")**,can't I use this way? I am confused~ help!

Comment: That means you have a line in the input that has either less or more than the two columns you're expecting in that line of code. Try that line in the scala shell with strings `"abcde"`  and `"a\tb\tc"` as input.

Comment: @vanza This should be an answer, not a comment (especially given the current answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax sugar for unpacking a pair in scala as:

```
val (id, info) = ("123", "word:123")
```

But this won't work for an Array returned by `split()` if the elements in the array don't match the number of parameters passed, just use a variable to capture the result and then use index to access the value in the Array:

```
sc.textFile("user_id.txt").map{ line =>
    val fields = line.split("\t")
    val info = fields(1).split(",").map { kv =>
        val pairs = kv.split(":")
        (pairs(0), pairs(1).toDouble)
    }.toSeq
    (fields(0), info)
}.collect()

# Array[(String, Seq[(String, Double)])] = Array((12334,WrappedArray((this,23.0), (word,21.0), (teacher,23.0))))
```

---

Obviously, I am not aware of the `unapply` method of Array when I had the above method, but I found it appealing to use the `unapply` method, and here is an alternative to follow the same philosophy as the above method by unpacking the array, and only take the first two fields of each line.

Which essentially follows this line, use `_*` to capture unwanted elements in the Array:

```
val Array(k, v, _*) = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
#k: Int = 1
#v: Int = 2
```

And the above method can rewritten as:

```
sc.textFile("user_id.txt").map{ line =>
    val Array(id, info_s, _*) = line.split("\t")
    val info = info_s.split(",").map { kv =>
        val Array(key, value, _*) = kv.split(":")
        (key, value.toDouble)
    }.toSeq
    (id, info)
}.collect()

# Array[(String, Seq[(String, Double)])] = Array((12334,WrappedArray((this,23.0), (word,21.0), (teacher,23.0))))
```

Comment: No, `val Array(id, info) = ...` as in the question, is perfectly legal. The problem is the number of elements in the array.

Comment: I have tried @Psidom's answer, it works. what's your mean about the number of elements ?

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax on line 5 (`val Array(k, v) = ...`) is using the Array [unapply method](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html).  You can get a match error if the number of bindings you supply in the extractor is not equal to the length of the array:

```
scala> val Array(k, v) = "1,2".split(",")
k: String = 1
v: String = 2

scala> val Array(k, v) = "1,2,3".split(",")
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@508dec2b (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
```

In your case, this is probably caused by malformed input (multiple `:` or none).  While extractors are useful and concise, their error messages are cryptic, so it's good practice to use slightly more verbose syntaxes if you aren't *positive* your match is correct (like reading arbitrary text files):

```
val (k, v) = kv.split(":") match {
  case Array(f1, f2) => (f1, f2)
  case Array(elems) => fatal("found invalid K/V pair: expected 2 elements, found ${elems.length}")
}
```